# How to match filenames under different directories using bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to write a bash script to search two given directories and will give me all the matching file names and the info on each file

I'm not sure where to start with this, I've been trying diff, find, grep and cant make anything work... any suggestions would be greatly appreciated thank you.

I did find that if i use diff -srq testdir1 testdir2 that it matches identical files, but if the size of one file changes it no longer matches, I just need to match by names.

Answer (score 3):

You want `join`.

I have two dirs, `a`, and `b`:

```
ls a b
a:
1  2  23 3

b:
1 3 4
```

`join` will join two (sorted) files line-by-line and print out the common rows:

```
$ join <(ls a) <(ls b)
1
3
```

Join works by joining on one field (fields are separated by tab and space characters) in each row in each file.  By default, that's the first field, but you can specifiy the field number if not the first.  Using that, you can use `ls -l` and add the extra file info:

```
$ join -1 9 -2 9 <(ls -l a) <(ls -l b)
 total 0 total 0
1 -rw-r--r-- 1 joeuser 5000 0 Sep 29 17:12 -rw-r--r-- 1 joeuser 5000 0 Sep 29 17:12
3 -rw-r--r-- 1 joeuser 5000 0 Sep 29 17:12 -rw-r--r-- 1 joeuser 5000 0 Sep 29 17:12
```

This combines both rows into one, so you can see the info about each file (in my example, they are the same because I created them at the same time).

When using this solution, be aware that `ls` output is not always reliable for parsing if you have non-word characters in filenames: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @ruakh As shown in my example, it joins the output of lines from both files.  You can even control that by cutting, or using a different `ls` command.  Thanks for the extra info on `ls`.  I still think it can be a decent solution where convenience is important.

Comment: @ruakh No worries, thanks :)  I'll incorporate your link into my post.

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like this:

```
cd testdir1
files_in_testdir1=(*)
cd "$OLDPWD"   # return to original directory
for file in "${files_in_testdir1[@]}" ; do
    if [[ -e testdir2/"$file" ]] ; then
        ls -ld testdir1/"$file" testdir2/"$file"
    fi
done
```

This populates an array named `files_in_testdir1` with the list of filenames in `testdir1`, then iterates over the array to identify the ones that exist in both directories.

Answer (score 0):

To recursively get all matching file names from anywhere in 2 directories:

```
find dir1 -type f | xargs basename | xargs -I {} find dir2 -iname "{}"
```

This finds all files in dir1, picks the filename off of the full path and then searches for that name under dir2.

You can use different arguments to the initial find command if you want to search for a certain extension, for example.